# Track files changes done by eclipse cleanup programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-jdt, code-cleanup

I have written one eclipse osgi plugin that runs cleanup and formatting actions on java files present in eclipse project.  Some thing like:

- Run batch file that has eclipse command
- It open's eclipse editor
- Loads eclipse project passed as parameter in batch command
- Run cleanup and formatting actions
- Closes eclipse

Now my problem is I need to track the files that has been changed by this action.  I am performing cleanup changes using `cleanUpsAction` that runs as thread over multiple files and forks further.  It returns void.

There is `IResourceChangeListener` which I tried as well but I am not able to get name of resources that are changed.  I get object of `IResourceChangeEvent` but details of resource are not coming out of it, it always return project name when I prints `IResourceChangeEvent.getSource()`.

Comment: Hi, I would like to invoke a cleanup action for a list of files in my plugin. After reading your post you may have an answer to this. I wonder if you can share how you call a cleanup action. Preferably I would like to apply a predefined cleanup profile again the list of file. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Tim -Yes now I am able to do it.  But right now I am working with company and code written is proprietary to them.  Still I have written a blog explaining complete logic and way to achieve this.  Please refer my blog @ http://sv-technical.blogspot.com/2015/09/osgi-update-java-source-code.html - Please visit this

Comment: Thanks for replying. I looked at the Eclipse source again and was able to figure out it. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple levels of object in the `IResourceChangeEvent` at the top is usually the project or the workspace and below that are folders and files. These are represented by `IResourceDelta` objects.

To see all of them first get the top level `IResourceDelta` from the event:

```
IResourceChangeEvent event = ... the event

IResourceDelta delta = event.getDelta();
```

and then use an `IResourceDeltaVisitor` to visit each resource in the delta:

```
delta.accept(visitor);
```

where `visitor` is a class implementing `IResourceDeltaVisitor`.

There is just one method in the visitor:

```
public boolean visit(IResourceDelta delta) throws CoreException
```

which is given a delta for each resource.

`IResourceDelta.getResource` gives you the changed resource. `IResourceDelta.getKind` tells you the type of change (add, delete, change).

Comment: Hi greg-449, I tried your way but facing some problem.  When I get delta from `IResourceChangeEvent` it always gives me list of all files with `IResourceDela.ADDED` status in project and later also trigger same file with event `IResourceDela.REMOVED`.  Let's say if I have four file out of which only three changed by cleanup, how to know that ?.  Can I get list of files that are actually changed.  I checked in file system and even modified time stamp does not change for that one unchanged file.

Comment: You get a list of everything that the workspace has seen been added, removed or changed. There is some additional information about what happened in the delta `getFlags()` call. If something is not changed you do not get any notification. I do not know of any way to find out about things that were not changed.

Comment: :( . Even `getFlags()` did not helped.  For now I use OS time stamp to find out changed files.  Might be I am missing something to get file details.  But I will surely revisit it and update here if I find something.